# How to make a List in Landscape Portrait

Tags: list, blackberry, landscape-portrait

On click of a Button 
I have created a List that comes out on the next Screen
Now i want to set it as Landscape Portrait
If the Height in Resolution is greater than its Width how do I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Blackberry, you cannot set the device orientation to landscape/portrait, unless the user holds in that way and then you set it in the app.

You can set the device to landscape using the following code.

```
Ui.getUiEngineInstance().setAcceptableDirections(Display.DIRECTION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Remember, this code **wont work** if you are holding the device in portrait mode. Turn the device into landscape mode and then run this code and the app is set to landscape mode from then on.

Comment: Won't i be able to Put at the click of button to start with LANDSCAPE mode

Comment: no you cant force orientation, unless the user is already holding the phone in landscape